# retrieving json data fails in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm sending json data to my php and then want to receive data back to my Jquery.ajax success but getting null value.

My code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: postUrl,
    data: queryString,
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
        switch(action) {
          case "edit":
          jsonData = data;
          $("#custEmail").val(jsonData[0].custEmail);
    break;
    //some more code
  }
});
```

In my php i am using this to retrieve data:

```
$jsonData = $_POST['action']; 
echo $jsonData;
```

Edit:

I see lot of fuss here. Json data which i am sending is

```
queryString = '{"action":"' + action+ '", "checkId":"' + id+ '"}';
```

and i am unable to receive using $_POST method.

Comment: Without seeing what the PHP is doing to return data, we are going to have to do a lot of guessing here

Comment: What do you see when you do a `console.log(data)` in the top of your success function? And show us your PHP that returns the data

Comment: But for starters, I dont see anywhere where you set a value into `action`

Comment: **Who UPVOTED this question**. Please read what an upvote signifies... PS: This question **fails on all 3 criteria**

Comment: Is that ALL that your PHP script does?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Either people must have multiple accounts where they upvote their own questions, or they ask some friend/coworker to upvote the questions. It's pretty common that really poor questions gets upvotes. Truly annoying... Good thing it's easy to rectify...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am VTC this as no MCV. Far too much is being left out of what is posted here, feel free to join me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is that you who downvoted me? why??? I'm just helping  out.

Comment: @Avnishalok - I get that you're just trying to help out and you should keep doing that, but your answer is actually wrong and not a solution to the OP's issue in any way.

Comment: You appear to be retuning a simple text string from your PHP. But in your AJAX code you appear to expect it to be returning an `action` and an `email address` into arbitrary variable names.

Comment: Check out `json_encode()` in the PHP manual and also Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference

Comment: I see lot of fuss here. Json data which i am sending is queryString = '{"action":"' + action+ '", "checkId":"' + id+ '"}';

Comment: Try `queryString = {action: action, checkId: id};`

Comment: If you had shown us all the relevant code you would have got an answer in no time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To receive json post data safest way to use is file_get_contents("php://input").

use:

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); //get json data
$data = $jsonData->yourdata;
```

Comment: jQuery will still make an ordinary POST request so the back end can definitely use `$_POST` to retrieve the data. `dataType: 'json'` only means that the request expects the _response_ to be json..  From the doc: _"**dataType:** The type of data that you're expecting back from the server"_. Here's the doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: While this is the safest way to collect the posted data, It is not true to say _$_POST can't be used_ I use it all the time

Comment: see my edits now.

Comment: This answer helped me. I don't know why people downvoted you. +1 for help.

Comment: @Avnishtiwary But it is not the correct answer. Only accept answer when they are correct and complete, otherwise others will get confused by the tick later